# Caching for special calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, functools

How can you change the behavior of the decorator `lru_cache` from `functools` so that the decorated function has a flag that indicates whether to cache this call or not.
for example

```
@new_lru_cache
def f(args, kwargs):
    ...body function...

f(1) # not saved
f(2, cache=True) # saved
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Added try......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are gonna write a whole function for it, why not copy-paste the original source and implement your logic there?

```
def lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False, cache=False):
    if isinstance(maxsize, int):
        if maxsize < 0:
            maxsize = 0
    elif callable(maxsize) and isinstance(typed, bool):
        user_function, maxsize = maxsize, 128
        wrapper = _lru_cache_wrapper(user_function, maxsize, typed, _CacheInfo)
        return update_wrapper(wrapper, user_function)
    elif maxsize is not None:
        raise TypeError('Expected first argument to be an integer, a callable, or None')

    def decorating_function(user_function):
        if not cache:
            return user_function # We add here
        wrapper = _lru_cache_wrapper(user_function, maxsize, typed, _CacheInfo)
        return update_wrapper(wrapper, user_function)

    return decorating_function
```

This way you have even more control over the function, and you can see everything easily, and you can play around with the inners of the functools this way.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this - an extension of `lru_cache`, allowing access to configure the cache.

```py
from functools import lru_cache

def controlled_lru_cache(*lru_args, **lru_kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        func_with_cache = lru_cache(*lru_args, **lru_kwargs)(func)
        def decorated(*args, cache=False, **kwargs):
            if cache:
                return func_with_cache(*args, **kwargs) 
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated
    return decorator

@controlled_lru_cache(maxsize=64)
def square(n):
    return n * n
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself.

```
def new_lru_cache(f):
    g = None
    def inner(*args, cache=False, **kwargs):
        if cache:
            nonlocal g
            if g is None:
                g = lru_cache(f)
            return g(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```